# How can I make spaces or URLs inside a code span with Markdown syntax?

Tags: markdown

I have a problem in writing Markdown.

I hope Markdown would compile ' a' to  `a`, but the space will be ignored, and the result is like this:

`a`

And also, I hope that in `[a](http://link.com)="1"`, "a" can be linked.

Is that impossible or is there a trick to solve this?

Or can I only use HTML as intended and use a `code` tag instead? For example, `<code>&nbsp;a</code>`?

But HTML in markdown seems not a good solution: [rule of MD033 - Inline HTML](https://github.com/markdownlint/markdownlint/blob/master/docs/RULES.md#md033---inline-html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a line with a space in pure Markdown, **use a zero-width space** in front of a regular space:

`<zero-width space><regular space>a`

This will result in:

> ​ a

instead of:

> a

You can copy a zero-width space from e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space#Usage).

However, **using `&nbsp;` is widely used in Markdown documents** and I'd encourage you to use it instead.

Also, you can use two code spans next to each other with a link attached to one of them. Sadly, there is no way to remove the space between the two parts (at least not in SO Markdown).

This:

`` [`linked`](http://example.com)<zero-width space>`not linked` ``

will result in this:

[`linked`](http://example.com)`not linked`

Comment: It seems that any character in backtick quotes (`) would be shown as itself.
So I don't want to use HTML tags in pure Markdown and has a space before a word cannot be achieved?